# Run dotnet core 3.1 app on Debian9, build on Windows10, use installed runtime on Debian

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I have simple HelloWorld project. Tried to build it on Windows10 and run on Debina9:

`dotnet build -c Release -r debian.9-x64`

Only copied two files:

- HelloWorld
- HelloWorld.dll

I don't want to copy all runtine .dlls and .sos if possible.
I get message:

> A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required
>   to execute the application was not found in '/usr/share/dotnet'.

On debian i tried:
`locate libhostpolicy.so`
Result: `/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.4/libhostpolicy.so`

So i added file global.json to make sure 3.1.4 is used ([SDK 3.1.4](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1)):

```
{
    "sdk": {
      "version": "3.1.300"
    }
}
```

And copied HelloWorld.deps.json to debian:

```
{
  "runtimeTarget": {
    "name": ".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1/debian.9-x64",
    "signature": ""
  },
  "compilationOptions": {},
  "targets": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1": {},
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1/debian.9-x64": {
      "HelloWorld/1.0.0": {
        "dependencies": {
          "runtimepack.Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.linux-x64": "3.1.4"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "HelloWorld.dll": {}
        }
      },
      "runtimepack.Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.linux-x64/3.1.4": {
        "runtime": {
...
```

But problem still remains, what did I miss/do wrong?

Comment: Did you try to run [`dotnet publish`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish) command? And then copy the app to debian host to run

Comment: No, only build and copied results.

Comment: Thx @PavelAnikhouski, publish with no --no-self-contained helped me to learn what files I need. Missed some in build.

Answer (score 1):

After doing: `dotnet publish -c Release -r debian.9-x64 --no-self-contained`
and copying few extra files to debian that I missed before everything works.